# Subtract a Series from a DataFrame while keeping the DataFrame struct intact

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

How can I subtract a Series from a DataFrame, while keeping the DataFrame struct intact?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((5,3)))
s = pd.Series(np.ones(5))

df - s
   0  1  2   3   4
0 -1 -1 -1 NaN NaN
1 -1 -1 -1 NaN NaN
2 -1 -1 -1 NaN NaN
3 -1 -1 -1 NaN NaN
4 -1 -1 -1 NaN NaN
```

What I would like to have is the equivalent of subtracting a scalar from the DataFrame

```
df - 1
   0  1  2
0 -1 -1 -1
1 -1 -1 -1
2 -1 -1 -1
3 -1 -1 -1
4 -1 -1 -1
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Maybe:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((5,3)))
>>> s = pd.Series(np.ones(5))
>>> df.sub(s,axis=0)
   0  1  2
0 -1 -1 -1
1 -1 -1 -1
2 -1 -1 -1
3 -1 -1 -1
4 -1 -1 -1

[5 rows x 3 columns]
```

or, for a more interesting example:

```
>>> s = pd.Series(np.arange(5))
>>> df.sub(s,axis=0)
   0  1  2
0  0  0  0
1 -1 -1 -1
2 -2 -2 -2
3 -3 -3 -3
4 -4 -4 -4

[5 rows x 3 columns]
```

Answer (score 2):

If a1 is a dataframe made of n columns and a2 is a another dataframe made by just 1 column, you can subtract a2 from **each** column of a1 using numpy

```
np.subtract(a1, a2)
```

You can achieve the same result if a2 is a Series making sure to transform to DataFrame

```
np.subtract(a1, a2.to_frame())
```

I guess that, before computing this operation, you need to make sure the indices in the two dataframes are coherent/overlapping. As a matter of fact, the above operations will work if a1 and a2 have the same number of rows and different indices. You can try

```
a1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=['a','b'])
a2 = pd.DataFrame([[1], [2]], columns=['c'])

np.subtract(a1, a2)
```

and

```
a1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=['a','b'])
a2 = pd.DataFrame([[1], [2]], columns=['c'], index=[3,4])

np.subtract(a1,a2)
```

will give you the same result.

For this reason, to make sure the two DataFrames are coherent, you could preprocess using something like:

```
def align_dataframes(df1, df2):
    r = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, join_axes=[df1.index])
    return r.loc[:,df1.columns], r.loc[:,df2.columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll throw in an example that modifies a subset of the a DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(20).reshape((2,10)),columns=list('abcdefghjk'))

>>> df
    a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   j   k
0   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
1  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19

# Series to be subtracted    
dif = df['g'] - df['h']

>>> dif
0   -1
1   -1
dtype: int32

# subtract the Series from columns 'g','h','j','k'
df.loc[:,'g':] = df.loc[:,'g':].subtract(dif,axis='rows')
#df.loc[:,'g':] = df.loc[:,'g':].subtract(dif,axis=0)

>>> df
    a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   j   k
0   0   1   2   3   4   5   7   8   9  10
1  10  11  12  13  14  15  17  18  19  20
```