# NotImplementedError: fill_value 0 not supported

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am relatively new to Python, and I am stuck at this point:

```
frame = DataFrame(np.arange(12.).reshape((4, 3)), columns=list('bde'),
index=['Utah', 'Ohio', 'Texas', 'Oregon'])
series = frame.iloc[:,0]
frame.sub(series, axis = 1,fill_value=0)
```

Gives this error:

```
    C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in _    combine_match_columns(self, other, func, level, fill_value)
    3470         if fill_value is not None:
    3471             raise NotImplementedError("fill_value %r not supported" %
->  3472                                       fill_value)
    3473 
    3474         new_data = left._data.eval(

    NotImplementedError: fill_value 0 not supported
```

But in the documentation of `Dataframe.sub` method, `fill_value` parameter is supported.

Can somebody explain this error?

Comment: It's strange because with turning series to DataFrame works well: `frame.sub(series.to_frame(), axis = 1,fill_value=0)`

Comment: I guess the need for `fill_value` is a superfluous one which could easily be done away with performing `fillna` as a prior step.

Comment: related question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20531990/subtract-a-series-from-a-dataframe-while-keeping-the-dataframe-struct-intact

Comment: Recommendation do not use `ix` it is deprecated. [see docs](
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#ix-indexer-is-deprecated
).  Look at using `.loc` or `.iloc` depending on if you are accessing by the column header label or position.

Comment: Seems like fill_value works with DataFrame objects, not Series.  If you convert the "series" into a df, in the line before the last, it works.

Answer (score 1):

The fill_value and related error message appears to be a red herring here.  To put it differently, `sub()` is getting confused by the alignment here, and it just happens to be that the fill_value is where it crashes.

To see this, take out the fill value:

```
frame.sub(series, axis = 1)
Out[194]: 
        Ohio  Oregon  Texas  Utah   b   d   e
Utah     NaN     NaN    NaN   NaN NaN NaN NaN
Ohio     NaN     NaN    NaN   NaN NaN NaN NaN
Texas    NaN     NaN    NaN   NaN NaN NaN NaN
Oregon   NaN     NaN    NaN   NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

That is almost certainly not what you intended.  Now if you inspect `series`, you'll see that it is named 'b':

```
series.name
Out[197]: 'b'
```

But pandas does not seemto automatically align a series named 'b' with the 'b' column of frame.  Whether it should or not, I don't know, but the fix suggested in the comment by @AntonProtopopv allows pandas to get the alignment of column 'b' correct.

```
frame.sub(series.to_frame(), axis = 1)
Out[195]: 
          b   d   e
Utah    0.0 NaN NaN
Ohio    0.0 NaN NaN
Texas   0.0 NaN NaN
Oregon  0.0 NaN NaN
```

I'm not sure exactly what you wanted to do here, but regardless of that, if you get the alignment straightened out first, then fill_value should work as expected.  Or to be honest, I'd probably just use `fillna` in a method chain as suggested by @NickilMaveli as that seems like the more explicit (and hence better) way to fill missing values.

One final note:  if you were meaning to use numpy broadcasting here (i.e. subtract column 'b' from all columns), it is often easier to convert to arrays first, and then perform operations like subtraction.

```
frame.values - series.values.reshape(4,1)
Out[204]: 
array([[0., 1., 2.],
       [0., 1., 2.],
       [0., 1., 2.],
       [0., 1., 2.]])
```